# Access error saying related record is needed

Tags: ms-access

So I have set up a database to record files in boxes. I already have all of my boxes entered onto their table, and we are going through and entering the data from the files.

```
+WarehouseTable            +FileTable              +FileStatus
-id                         -id                   -id
-box                         -data                 -who
                                                    -date
```

For my inventory form, I have the box inventory as the main form, and then a subform to enter each file within the box. I also have hidden fields on the subform to save the user and date on a separate table for every record entered.

So when the user signs in, they navigate to their box number, and then are free to enter the file records in a datasheet style format. So when they tab down to the next record, some people keep getting error messages saying that a related record is needed. But it only happens to certain computers.

I've looked at the record sources for the forms and they seem to be fine. I haven't had data entry turned on so that they can see what records have been filled out all ready. Do you think that could cause an error?

Because all of the boxes are recorded already, I am unsure why it keeps saying a related record is needed from that table.

Comment: Those tables are extremely basic and abstract. I just was giving an idea behind the process

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I originally had a subform with links to multiple tables just by dragging and dropping fields from the toolbar pane. That was a terrible idea. I did not realize that each form should be linked to one table....if its not part of a query. 
So I then nested a second subform within the first subform. This would have worked, however, was too complicated for my taste. I would like to learn how to properly do that in the future. I just couldn't get the subform1 to start a new record in subform2, so that it would be one to many(parent to subform1), then a one to many from that(subform1 to subform2).

In the end I wrote a small procedure in my after insert event of subform1, that input subform2's data via VBA. So I ended up just deleting subform2 and entered it manually.

One challenge, which sent me on this adventure, is having ten users entering records at the same time. This is where my original errors where stemming from. So I turned all record locks off besides the default box in the startup options, and the rest is optimistic locking.

I then, with out much knowledge tweaked the refresh rates and what not....not sure if it helped or not.

So anyways, I guess the moral of the story is that I need to work on trapping errors, and creating my own error handlers so that I can figure this stuff out more efficiently. So yeah, I am answering my own question. If you are on the same path as I, go ahead and look for previous Access VBA documentation and textbooks. I found a great deal of PDF's on google and they have been life savers!!!